# how to correctly use a bash variable containing multiple arguments (which may contain spaces)

Tags: bash, shell

How can I pass a variable that contains spaces to a script so that the script processes them correctly?

My minimal example:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=1
for i in "$@"; do echo "$COUNTER '$i'"; ((COUNTER++)); done
```

If I call the script directly with some arguments (escaped space) it works:

```
./test.sh 1 2 3\ 4 5
```

Output (as expected):

```
1 '1'
2 '2'
3 '3 4'
4 '5'
```

If I store the arguments into a variable, the backslash is not interpreted correctly anymore as a escape char.

```
TEST_ARGS="1 2 3\ 4 5"
./test.sh $TEST_ARGS
```

Output:

```
1 '1'
2 '2'
3 '3\'
4 '4'
5 '5'
```

I would like to get the same output like before. How can I reach it?

```
TEST_ARGS="1 2 3\ 4 5"
# how to call ./test.sh here?
```

My more detailed use case is, that I have some script, which prepares all flags for my other tools / scripts.

prepare_flags.sh (very minimalistic):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'TEST_ARGS="1 2 3\ 4 5"'
```

In my actual script I source the output of the prepare_flags.sh script in order to access TEST_ARGS:

```
source <( ./prepare_flags.sh )
./test.sh $TEST_ARGS # this fails
bash -c "./test.sh $TEST_ARGS" # this works
```

Is there any other solution for this except the bash -c?

Comment: You are mentioning _bash array_ in your question, but there is no array in your code.

Answer (score 7):

Use an array, not a plain variable.

(Also, there is no reason to use ancient external tools like `expr` with Bash; `((++COUNTER))` would work just fine. (Also, it is better to avoid uppercase variable names, because those are (by convention) used for environment variables.))

`test.sh`:

```sh
for ((i = 1; i <= $#; ++i)); do echo "${i} '${!i}'"; done
```

Passing the arguments:

```sh
test_args=(1 2 '3 4' 5)
./test.sh "${test_args[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found some solution which seems to work so far:

```
TEST_ARGS="1 2 3\ 4 5"
bash -c "./test.sh $TEST_ARGS"
```

Output:

```
1 '1'
2 '2'
3 '3 4'
4 '5'
```

Comment: Your question is great but I must warn against this answer. It's effectively the same as `eval`, which opens the door for code injection attacks. A malicious user could get your script to execute arbitrary commands such as with `TEST_ARGS='1 2 3; rm -rf /'`. It will also be difficult to put the backslashes in the right places if you're building `TEST_ARGS` at runtime.

Comment: Adding another layer of expansion/indirection with `eval` or `bash -c`, such that escapes or quotes in variables will work, creates a significant code injection bug/vulnerability, because it means command list operators will also work. So arbitrary shell code in `TEST_ARGS` will be executed, as per @JohnKugelman's example.

Comment: I have explained my use case a little bit more detailed in the question now.